# Bootstrap table detail view no plus icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-table

In bootstrap table detail view there is a plus icon in each an every row. I'm using some styles to remove that Plus icon. Then it effects other tables as well. in other tables also the first column of the entire table get hides. Can i please know a solution for this.

```
.detail-view-table thead > tr > th.detail,
.detail-view-table tbody > tr:not(.detail-view) > td:first-of-type {
display: none;
}
.detail-view-table thead > tr > th:nth-child(2),
.detail-view-table tbody > tr:not(.detail-view) > td:nth-child(2) {
border-left: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with you full code, html and css, to see what is happening and where is the plus icon :)

Comment: I think this is because you've added this `detail-view-table` for all your table. So just create a new selector `other-detail-view-table` and add it only for this table.

Comment: no i haven't add that class to each n every table. but still it effects the other table s as well. BTW what does other-detail-view-table this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `parent child` selector CSS, whereby, you need to declare a `class` for the parent element of the table.

For instance, if the table is inside the `div`, then add a `class` called `.hide` and take this as a parent and then select your child table.

**Example**

```
.hide .detail-view-table thead > tr > th.detail,
.hide .detail-view-table tbody > tr:not(.detail-view) > td:first-of-type {
display: none;
}
```

Doing this will not affect other tables, but, table that you want to get affected.

This will give you what you are looking for.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The other table is a table inside a table. As in the other table is in the detail view area of the same table where i have remove the plus icon.

Comment: @shashinipiyaratne - Simply apply class to the parent, target its child and you will get your plus icons removed for that part only like you want

Comment: Both the tables are in same div. AS in table within a table.

Comment: @shashinipiyaratne - Apply class to the parent div that has the table that you want to target